# Excel 2013 Search for substring in column using lookup column and return accompanying value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 sheets:

sheet1 contains 2 columns as follows:

```
columnA   columnB
AB        Texas
BC        California
DE        Virginia
```

sheet2 contains 1 columns as follows:

```
columnA
AB_documentOne.pdf   
BC_documentTwo.pdf   
DE_documentThree.pdf 
AB_documentFour.pdf  
AB_documentFive.pdf  
DE_documentSix.pdf
```

In adjacent column "columnB" in sheet2, I would to extract the correct values from columnB in sheet1.

Desired result:

```
columnA               columnB
AB_documentOne.pdf    Texas
BC_documentTwo.pdf    California
DE_documentThree.pdf  Virginia
AB_documentFour.pdf   Texas
AB_documentFive.pdf   Texas
DE_documentSix.pdf    Virginia
```

I tried:

```
=INDEX(sheet1!B:B,MATCH(sheet1!A:A,sheet2!A:A,0))
```

Since I am using columnA from sheet1 as a substring lookup for columnA in sheet2, this will produce an error.

Excel version: 2013

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are cases where columnA in sheet2 will not have the lookup value from columnA in sheet1 as a prefix, e.g. H103_AB_documentSeven.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the following to work with a LEFT(string,2) mod to your lookup, switch the order of the match parameters, and switch A:A to a specific cell, but anchor the column so you can copy it down the column without issue:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(LEFT(Sheet2!$A1,2),Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

[image]

**EDIT FOR FOLLOW-UP COMMENT**:

To find your target string anywhere in the full text, the only way I have been able to make it work is using array formulas (must enter them by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>) and using a COUNTIF() trick I found [here](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/10/09/find-text-with-index-and-match/) for first finding the index of where the target string starts matching the full text.

The COUNTIF() finds which of your target strings is found (actually it gives you a count of matches), then use the index of which string has 1 match by using MATCH(), and then your INDEX() grabs the corresponding state name that goes along with the match that was found.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&Sheet1!A:A&"*"),0))
```

Comment: Great success!! That worked perfectly. Much appreciated!

Comment: How would it work if the substring is not always at the beginning or end, but somewhere in the middle?

Comment: @Sconny Give that edit a shot

Comment: I absolutely tried before asking. :)

Comment: This is what I tried: =INDEX(ContentTypes!B:B,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(master!I2,"*"&ContentTypes!A:A&”*”),0)) --> No bueno

Comment: Based on all the research, the answer is to use a wild card.

Comment: @Sconny Yeah, you will need the asterisk(*) between the quotes on both ends of your &ContentTypes!A:A& for it to match it in the middle of string names. It's building a search string that says "find *AB * anywhere in H103_AB_documentSeven.pdf".  The ""&ContentTypes!A:A&"" is still looking for an exact match.

Comment: That worked! Excellent.